# How to use Vue 3 built-in directives when custom directive?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to create a custom directive to show a menu when an element is clicked. But you know using `addEventListener` directly is different from setting `v-on:click` on the element. Built-in directives tend to include more preprocessing.

So I want to use built-in directives in a custom directive. The documentation has no relevant usage, any ideas?

example:

```html
<div v-menu="options" />
```

will equivalent to

```html
<div v-on:click.right.self.prevent="menuFunction(options)" />
```

Comment: please share the code of the custom directive

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim The code of the custom directive doesn't matter. Wondering how to use built-in directives in code, not in a template